# Confusion in linear dependency

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Do the columns of A form a linearly dependent set?

Do the rows of A form a linearly dependent set?
Edit: I know how to do it for columns. It is just for the rows I am confused for.

Comment: Hint: what is the maximal size of a linearly independent set in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us look at how a linear combination of the rows might yield the null vector:
\begin{align}
\sum_i \lambda_i r_i &= 
(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3)
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\\
&=
(\lambda_1, 2\lambda_1-\lambda_2, \lambda_2 + \lambda_3, 4\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 + 3\lambda_3)
\\
&= (0,0,0,0)
\end{align}
What will comparison of the components tell you about the coefficients $\lambda_i$? What does this mean for the linear independence of the rows?

Comment: that each of the lambda value should be zero . hence proving that rows of A form a linearly independent set. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a standard theorem in linear algebra:

> **Theorem.** Let $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_s\}$ be a collection of vectors in a vector space $V$. If $s>\dim(V)$, then $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_s\}$ is linearly dependent.

In your case, the columns of $A$ form a collection $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ of vectors in $\Bbb R^3$. Since $4>3=\dim(\Bbb R^3)$ our theorem tells us that the columns of $A$ form a linearly dependent collection.

A more refined theorem can also be used:

> **Theorem.** Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix. Then the columns of a matrix $A$ form a linearly dependent subset of $\Bbb R^m$ if and only if $\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank(A)<\#\DeclareMathOperator{columns}{columns}\columns(A)$.

In our case, we have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 2 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & -4 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3
\end{array}\right]
$$
so $\rank(A)=3$ while $\#\columns(A)=4$. Hence the columns of $A$ form a linearly dependent collection.

Now, what about the rows of $A$?

Note that the rows of $A$ are exactly the columns of $A^\top$. So, to determine if the rows of $A$ form a linearly dependent set, we may apply our second theorem to $A^\top$. Since $\rank(A)=\rank(A^\top)=3=\#\columns(A^\top)$ our theorem implies that the columns of $A^\top$ are linearly independent. Hence the rows of $A$ are linearly independent.

Comment: thanks for the lot for this. It helped me get a good grasp on my info. But what about the "rows" of A(The main question). Do they form a dependent set or independent set?

Comment: Note that the rows of $A$ are exactly the columns of $A^\top$. So, we need only apply the second theorem to $A^\top$ to determine if the rows of $A$ are linearly independent. I've updated my answer to address this.